# How to trace error in react native in reflux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, refluxjs

how can i trace this error? [screen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjNyV.jpg)
I can find 'apply' property in my code.
Thanks for the help!

I found error by commenting every function

```
  onLoadUser: function (user) {
    Actions.loadUser.completed(user); // at this place catch error
  },
  onLoadUserCompleted: function (user) {
    this.setCurrentUser(user);
  },

  setCurrentUser(user) {
    currentUser = {
      user_id: user.user_id,
      token: user.access_token,
      username: user.username,
      email: user.email
    }
  },

  getCurrentUser() {
    return currentUser;
  },
```

Why is it happening?(

Answer (score 0):

If you're conected to the debug server, usually after a second or two, the bundled lines are replaced with the source code files & lines. 
If not, you could enable remote debugging in your development menu, and debug the flow using chrome.

You can read more about debugging react-native applications in Facebook documentations:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html

Comment: it's not show errors in my source code files, just in react native's files

Comment: can u show as some code? to try to understand what u r doing wrong?

Comment: It's hard to tell from this. I'd say your code has some undefined function that's called somehow somewhere, probably by react native.
Like I said in my answer. try to remote debug in chrome and see where exactly in your code this error starts..

Comment: http://dl1.joxi.net/drive/2016/07/05/0016/2340/1079588/88/a3a5933202.jpg

Comment: This is very weird.are u sure the function exists? Try to call alert(Actions.loadUser.completed) and see if the popup shows undefined or function

Comment: it's undefined, but why? onLoadUserCompleted: function (user) exist below

Comment: I'm not familiar with reflux datastore, but you might not configuring something properly, or not calling the right function? Try alert(Actions.loadUser) and see what properties u have there..